# Word form after MEAN

Tags: grammar, gerund-vs-infinitive

Help me with this question, please.

I know that if we use **mean+gerund** it means having a result (can be replaced with 'involve') as in *Working from home means being able to keep work-life balance*.
If we use **mean+infinitive** it means having intention as in *I didn't mean to hurt you*.

However, I found the following example in Oxford dictionary - *Do you have any idea what it means to be poor?* 
According to the rule we should use -ing in the sentence.

Why is an infinitive used in the sentence?

Comment: What it means to be poor = what being poor means.

Comment: As Lambie says. This is a totally different construction. 'Rules' rarely cover every eventuality. Compare your problem example with 'Do you have any idea what it takes/costs to be successful?' Obviously, *'I didn't cost to hurt you' shows that something very different is happening here.